# Java Bean Validation: GroupSequence with Class-Level Constraint

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a bean class with multiple (custom) inner constraints and one class-level constraint. I'd like to validate the inner constraints before the class-level constraint. The code looks like this:

```
@GroupSequence({ Inner.class, NewSlotBean.class })
@TotalBeanValid(groups = NewSlotBean.class)
public class NewSlotBean {

    @DayMonthYearString(groups = Inner.class)
    private String slotDay;

    @TimeString(groups = Inner.class)
    private String slotBegin;

    @LengthString(groups = Inner.class)
    private String slotLength;
}
```

(`Inner` is just an empty interface lying around somewhere).

However, when I try to run this, the class-level constraint does not get validated at all. When I try to define the GroupSequence like

```
@GroupSequence({ Inner.class, Outer.class })
```

(with `Outer` being a random interface), I get the exception:

```
javax.validation.GroupDefinitionException: ...*.beans.NewSlotBean must be part of the redefined default group sequence.
```

Does s/o know how to make sure that the class-level constraint is validated after the inner ones? (This appears not to be the default! I've had random problems with it popping up after a while.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
@GroupSequence({ Inner.class, NewSlotBean.class })
@TotalBeanValid(groups = Default.class)
public class NewSlotBean {

    @DayMonthYearString(groups = Inner.class)
    private String slotDay;

    @TimeString(groups = Inner.class)
    private String slotBegin;

    @LengthString(groups = Inner.class)
    private String slotLength;
}
```

According to the spec *NewSlotBean* is just a stand-in for the default group. See also section 3.4.3 of the Bean Validation spec:

> Since sequences cannot have circular dependencies, using Default in
>   the declaration of a sequence is not an option. Constraints hosted on
>   a class A and belonging to the Default group (by default or
>   explicitly) implicitly belong to the group A.
>
> A sequence defined on a class A (i.e. redefining the Default groups
>   for the class) must contain the group A. In other words, the default
>   constraints hosted on a class must be part of the sequence definition.
>   If a @GroupSequence redefining the Default group for a class A does
>   not contain the group A, a GroupDefinitionException is raised when
>   Constraint declaration and validation process the class is validated
>   or when its metadata is requested.

Comment: Just an improvement suggestion to an excellent answer: it's probably better to group the validations the other way around:
`@GroupSequence({ NewSlotBean.class, ClassLevel.class }) @TotalBeanValid(groups = ClassLevel.class)` on the `NewSlotBean` class and then remove the `InnerGroup` validation group and the field level group assignments - the field validations are autmatically assigned to the default validation group. Less code, cleaner.

Comment: @jannis which jar contains annotation @TotalBeanValid? Thanks

Comment: @italktothewind, I believe that TotalBeanValid is just a custom validation annotation.