# Java Bean Validation: How to cascade validations with validation groups?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a class-level annotation which I use to check `someField` before checking another field with type `Bar`

```java
@SomeClassValidation
class Foo {
    String someField;

    @Valid
    Bar someBar;
}
```

the implementation for `ConstraintValidator<SomeClassValidation, Foo>` looks something like:

```java
if(someField == someExpectedValue) {
    return someBar != null;
}
```

When the initial checks done with `@SomeClassValidation` pass, I also need to validate the fields inside the `Bar` class which looks something like:

```java
class Bar {
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=2, max=2)
    String fieldA;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=3, max=10)
    String fieldB;
}
```

Following [the answer in another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380209/java-bean-validation-groupsequence-with-class-level-constraint), I figured I need to use validation groupings where `BarValidationGroup` is a marker interface I used for the fields in `Bar` class.

```java
@SomeClassValidation
@GroupSequence({Foo.class, BarValidationGroup.class})
class Foo {
    String someField;

    @Valid
    Bar someBar;
}

class Bar {
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=2, max=2, groups = BarValidationGroup.class)
    String fieldA;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=3, max=10, groups = BarValidationGroup.class)
    String fieldB;
}
```

The first level validation (`@SomeClassValidation`) triggers but the validations for `Bar` doesn't. What am I doing wrong?